# Enabled EditText after clicked a radio button in radio group Android Studio

Tags: android

I have one `RadioGroup` and inside it have 6 radio button. If the user clicks at the 6th radio button, an `EditText` will enable to type. Else, the `EditText` will remain disabled. I tried many solutions on this website but still got some error. The most common error is the `EditText` remain disable although I set it to enable when the 6th radio button is clicked. Below is the code for XML:

```
 <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp">

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/rgSuggestWill"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:checkedButton="@+id/rbSaveCost">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rbSaveCost"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:focusable="auto"
                    android:text="Save Cost"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rbRevenue"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:focusable="auto"
                    android:text="Increase Revenue"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rbQuality"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:focusable="auto"
                    android:text="Improve Quality"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rbWorkProcess"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:focusable="auto"
                    android:text="Improve Work Process Efficiency"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rbSafety"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:focusable="auto"
                    android:text="Improve Safety"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rbOwnValue"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:focusable="auto"
                    android:text="Specify your own value: "
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
            </RadioGroup>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etOwnValue"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@layout/rounded_border_edittext"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Others" />
        </TableRow>
```

Comment: You need to post some code which is relevant as well. So that we can understand the problem better. Please do not post the whole code which will create confusions.

Answer (score 0):

this may help you:

```
// getting the groug
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.yourRadioGroup);  

    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
if(checkedId==6) {
// if the id of the checkedId equels to the id of the 6 button than make the editText enable 

myEditText.setEnable(true)
} else {
// else (wich mean that other redio button been clicked) make it disable.
myEditText.setEnable(false)
}
        }
    });
```

and in the xml decide your stating state (enable or disable)

Comment: thanks for your contribution. it seems to be successful. when I click 6th RB, the edit text will enable, the ichange to the 5th RB, the edittext remain enable.

Comment: hi, check the id that you getting